# How to substitute in multiple lines?

Tags: command-line, search, substitute

I'd like to insert a word in multiple lines, is there any command like

```
:[2,3,5,7,11]s/^/word\ /g
```

which would insert `word` at the beginning of line 2, line 3, line 5, line 7 and line 11?

Here, multiple lines are not contiguous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Performing a substitution on several consecutive lines is pretty easy:

```
:2,11s/^/word /
```

but a range can't cover non-consecutive lines.

With a bit of creativity, though, it is entirely possible to work around that "limitation".

Indeed, you can repeat the last substitution with `:&` or `:&&` (the former will not preserve the original flags, the latter will) so you can chain substitutions pretty easily:

```
2s/^/word /|3&|5&|7&|11&
```

See `:help :&` and scroll around for `:&&`.